# how to use dispatch in a right way?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

here is an example:

```
export const fetchPosts = (path, postData) => {
    let url = target + path + Tool.paramType(postData);
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(requestPosts(postData));
        return fetch(url,{
            mode: 'cors',
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        })
        .then(response => {
            if(response.ok){
                response.json().then(json => dispatch(receivePosts(path, json)))
            }else{
                console.log("status", response.status);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
}
```

when I want to request data in my commponent:

```
this.props.fetchPosts(this.props.seting.url,this.props.seting.data)
```

however,when I import like this:

```
import *as action from '../../Redux/Action/Index';
action.fetchPosts(this.props.seting.url,this.props.seting.data)
```

project seems to start successfully...Is that right?..... =.=

Comment: Whats the point ? You map actions to props in your container component. Why would you want to do it the other way ?

Comment: In simple words, the first approach is the right way - dont import actions individually in all components. Thats not recommended

Comment: When I try the second approach，there seems to be no mistake，now I know the drawbacks,  thx for sharing  @Arshabh Agarwal

Answer (score 1):

In order to make `fetchPosts` available as a prop to your component you need to make use of `mapDispatchToProps` function and `bindActionCreators` like

```
import *as action from '../../Redux/Action/Index';

......
mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
     return {
          fetchPosts: bindActionCreators(action.fetchPosts, dispatch);
     }

}
```

Also you need to make use of `connect` from redux to bind actions to the component like

```
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(componentName);
```

and this is the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
  import { connect } from 'react-redux'
  import { 
    requestPosts, 
    receivePosts 
  } from '../../Redux/Action/Index';

  export const fetchPosts = (path, postData) => {    
    const url = target + path + Tool.paramType( dispatch(requestPosts(postData)) );
    const { dispatch } = props

    return fetch(url, {
        mode: 'cors',
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    })
    .then(response => {
        if(response.ok){
            response.json().then(json => dispatch(receivePosts(path, json)))
        }else{
            console.log("status", response.status);
        }
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
}

export default connect(componentName);
```

When you use `connect`, `dispatch` automatically becomes available in `props` so you can invoke it directly by including it in your deconstructing of props. It seems that in your code, you are passing `postData` to the `Tool.paramType` before it has been defined, and it is not defined until after the return - I can't say that does not work or does, it just seems like it *could* fail - so I moved that dispatch directly into where the data is needed *when* it's needed. The answer above mine is also correct, these are just different ways of using dispatch and I have done both - recently I stopped using `mapDispatchToProps` once i learned it is already available on props via `connect` except in cases where I need to `bindActionCreators` , and that is needed when you are passing dispatch down to a lower level component that has no idea of redux.